# JavaFX 2: Passing mouse events through to other windows?

Tags: events, popup, window, mouseevent, javafx-2

I created a PopUp which is draggable across the screen, like a photoshop palette independent of the main window.

However, I would like the main window to react when I drag this PopUp over it, i.e. receive the mouse events from the drag.

The problem seems to be that since the PopUp is a Window itself, it consumes the dragging mouse events, and the main window never gets them.

I tried making the main windows the owner of the PopUp, however it still doesn't get them.

Is there any way to get around this ? Thanks

Comment: Node class has a method fireEvent(Event), which can be used for events simulation. You can simulate them for content of the target window, if you will track the position of mouse on popup, and popup position relative to the target scene. At least, we use it for some mouse events generation in tests on JavaFX, so it works.

Possibly, there is a better solution..